# How do you access an "Any" type object's properties?

Tags: ios, swift

So there's the following method call, and I'm trying to access the `r` object's properties, but I just don't know how to access them.

```swift
methodChannel.invokeMethod("DoSomething",arguments: link, result: { (r: Any?) -> () in
    debugPrint("invoked method")
    // TODO: How do I access r's properties?
})
```

Here's how it looks in the debugger viewer:

[image]

How do I access the `message` property inside the `r` object?

Comment: It seems to be a `FlutterError`. You should be able to cast to that type.

Answer (score 1):

You can't access the properties of `Any` as it is has none - it just represents an unspecified type.  To access the properties of the instance you will need to cast it to its concrete type.

By the look of the debugger output, the underlying type is `FlutterError` so you can access it's properties like

```
if let error = r as? FlutterError {
  // access any properties of FlutterError
} else {
  //handle it not being the FlutterError type you expected!
}
```